# JSON.stringify with square brackets

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have a JS object:

```
var source = {};
source.quantity = 1;
source.text = 'test';
```

Now I JSON it:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(source);
```

json looks like this:

```
{"quantity":"1","text":"test"}
```

I would like it to be like this:

```
[{"quantity":"1"},{"text":"test"}]
```

Ho can I do this?

Comment: The "square brackets" represent an array. So all you have to do is stringify an array. However, why do you want to single out each property into its own object? That doesn't seem to be very useful.

Comment: @FelixKling because PHP json_decode() does not like this: {"quantity":"1","text":"test"}

Comment: That is nonsense, of course `json_decode` understands valid JSON: http://ideone.com/WobRm8

Comment: @FelixKling, when I receive the above json on the server the data looks like this: `{quantity: 1, text : "test"}` After json_decode I have end up with a mess: `stdClass Object ([[], 1, []]) ` What do I miss here?

Comment: The problem might be that I loose the quotes somewhere so my valid json won't be valid any more. I use Sencha `Ext.Ajax.request({` to send and receive it with CodeIgniter's `$json = $this->input->post('json');`

Comment: `{quantity: 1, text : "test"}` is definitely not valid JSON and PHP should actually return an error when trying to parse it. I don't know what Sencha does to the data. Are you sure you are sending JSON and not a JavaScript object? (i.e. do you `JSON.stringify` the data before you send it?)

Comment: @FelixKling the problem was not around coding or decoding JSON but the way I used Google Chrome's dev tool. I was checking the server's response on the `Preview` tab. When I accidentally clicked on `Response` I saw that all looks as it should. Apologize. What shall I do with this question now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all the [**keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as an *Array* them [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them to *Objects* as *key-value* pairs from `source`

```
JSON.stringify(
    Object.keys(source)
          .map(
              function (e) {
                  var o = {};
                  o[e] = source[e];
                  return o;
              }
          )
); // "[{"quantity":1},{"text":"test"}]"
```

Comment: The OP wants an array with two objects (I know! don't ask me why).

Comment: @FelixKling This is such a bad data structure, where you have to guess (or attempt to find) keys :/

Comment: My issue was not related to the json format, however this post answered the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = JSON.stringify([
    {quantity: "1"},
    {text: "test"}
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not possible but you can do this:

```
var source = {};
source.quantity = 1;
source.text = 'test';

var result = [];

for(var i in source) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[i] = source[i];
    result.push(obj);
}

var json = JSON.stringify(result);
```

I hope this can help you.